# Grid.maxHeight is ignored

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I am trying to do an overlay (with a TextBox element inside) with a grid element, but setting the maxHeight to Window.current.Bounds.Height does not help, the grid still grows larger than the screenheight. Here is the xaml code:

```
<Grid x:Name="testGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <TextBox Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" AcceptsReturn="True"/>
</Grid>
```

and in the constructor of the page i am doing:

```
testGrid.MaxHeight = Window.Current.Bounds.Height;
```

When I type into the textbox it grows in height (as it should) but it grows larger than the screen. What needs to be changed?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove `Height="Auto"` from your `RowDefinition` (btw you don't need to define `RowDefinition`s if you have just one element within the `Grid`), and set `ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"` for the `TextBox`.

Comment: It's just a simplified example, in the real overlay there are several rows. And the rowHeight needs to be set to Auto, as otherwise it happens that the lower end of the TextBox disappears (the TextBox just keeps growing, but the row doesn't and so the lower part of the TextBox is not shown. The default of the height is 1* resulting in equally heigh rows if the others are not set, too)

Comment: Try to set explicit Height and `ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"`on the TextBox.

Answer (score 0):

Why not set the TextBox' MaxHeight?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the Grid's `VerticalAlignment="Stretch"` this should cause the Grid to not expand past the visible screen and then the textbox should not grow past the screen.